# Why does calling the YUI Datatable showCellEditor not display the editor?

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

Clicking on the second cell (any row) in the datatable causes the cell editor to display. But, I am trying to display the cell editor from code. The code looks like the following:

```
    var firstEl = oDataTable.getFirstTdEl(rowIndex);
    var secondCell = oDataTable.getNextTdEl(firstEl);
    oDataTable.showCellEditor(secondCell);
```

When I debug into the datatable.js code (either with a click or from the code above) it follows the same path through the showCellEditor function but the above code will not display the editor.

I am using YUI version 2.8.0r4.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is blur events issue.

So, for example, I have link that must add record to datatable, and show its editor.

```
var mymethod = function (e) {
  YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(e);
  var r = {};
  r.id = 0;
  r.value = 'hello world';

  myDataTable.addRow(r);
  var cell = myDataTable.getLastTrEl().cells[0];
  myDataTable.showCellEditor(cell);        
}

YAHOO.util.Event.addListener('mylink2addrecord_ID', 'click', mymethod);
```

Without stopEvent you will never see editor, because there is tableBlur event called when you click on yourlink....

Answer (score 0):

As mac said, you need to stop the previous event. For some reason it (the tableBlur event) conflicts with the showCellEditor function. This is the first place which had a resolution to the problem.

To sum it up, all I did was:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(window.event);<br/>
dt.showCellEditor(td); // dt = yui datatable obj, td = {record: yuirecord, column: yuicolumn}
```

Of course if you have the event object readily available as mac's post does, you can pass it to stopEvent(e) like he did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - this is ONLY a snippet from a larger piece of an event handler set of code I have.  EditNext is the function that moves over a cell and displays the editor, if the cell has one:

```
   this.myDataTable.subscribe("editorKeydownEvent",function(oArgs) {
            var self = this,
                ed = this._oCellEditor,  // Should be: oArgs.editor, see: http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui2/ticket/2513909
                ev = oArgs.event,
                KEY = YAHOO.util.KeyListener.KEY,
                Textbox = YAHOO.widget.TextboxCellEditor,
                Textarea = YAHOO.widget.TextareaCellEditor,
                DCE = YAHOO.widget.DateCellEditor,
                cell = ed.getTdEl(),
                col = ed.getColumn(),
                row,rec,

                editNext = function(cell) {
                    cell = self.getNextTdEl(cell);
                    while (cell && !self.getColumn(cell).editor) {

                        cell = self.getNextTdEl(cell);
                    }
                    if (cell) {
                        self.showCellEditor(cell);
                    }
                },
```